# Issue with the Decimal part of a Number Java

Tags: java, operation

Well i am making this operations in a program in java

```
public class results{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double x=Math.sqrt(1/8);
        double x2 = x*2;
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(x2);
    }
}
```

The problem is the variable x. It prints 0.0 and variable x2 0.0 as well. The result of x is 0.353553. How to fix this in order to use the 0.353553 instead of the 0.0 in variable x.

Comment: use 1.0/8 or (double)1/8 or 0.125

Comment: Please click the check mark on the left of the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

`1/8` is an integer division. The result is 0 so everything is zero. Try `1/8.0` or `0.125` instead.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept my answer to mark this question as solved. Thank you.

Comment: You could also use `1f/8f` or `1d/8d` to specify that those numbers are not intended as integers

Answer (score 0):

You can solved this problem that `1d` divided by `8d`.

```
double x=Math.sqrt(1d/8d);
double x2 = x*2d;
```